# Difference between votes, the vote, vote

Tags: nouns

According to Oxford's advanced learner's dictionary **the vote** means total number of votes cast. And **vote** means a choice 
 But I found a sentence 
 The main opposition boycotted last year’s presidential election, which Mr. Maduro won with **67.8% vote**.
 Is it correct? According to me it should be **67.8% of the vote**.

Comment: "a 67.8% vote" is OK. It means "a 67.8% voting result"

Answer (score 1):

### You are correct. It should be "67.8% of the vote".